# Please explain me following code. interfaces, class

Tags: class, interface

I am not able to understand following piedce of code.
Specifically, this line of code

```
al.Sort(new reverseSort());
```

**Code:**

```
public class reverseSort : IComparer
{
    int IComparer.Compare(Object x, Object y)
    {
        return ((new CaseInsensitiveComparer()).Compare(y, x));
    }
}

ArrayList al = new ArrayList();
        al.AddRange(new string[] { "Hello", "world", "this", "is", "a", "test" });

        al.Sort(new reverseSort());

        foreach (object s in al)
            Console.WriteLine(s.ToString());
```

**Output:**

world
this
test
is
Hello
A

Answer (score 0):

```
al.Sort(new reverseSort());
```

Calls [Sort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwx6zbd4.aspx) on your array `al`, using a custom defined comparer `reverseSort`, which is defined with the opposite sense of ordering to the default comparer